# Normalizing election voter data for choropleth?

Tags: choropleth

I would like to create a choropleth that shows eligible voters per constituency. This data is in raw count.

How do I normalize the data in this case?

My intention is to show the difference in number of eligible voters for each constituency.

One thing I have done is shown how much each constituency deviates from the average. In some cases this is extreme and I have a range of variation between - 99% and 328%, so also having trouble representing this properly in buckets.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to include the software you are using, the data you have available, and an example of what you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to normalize your data, I believe what you are trying to do is standardize it.  A commonly used method to do this would be using a z-score, which will standardize any data set in terms of the data sets mean and standard deviation.  Here is a link to a Wikipedia article with the details:

[Z Scores](https://arstechnica.com/science/2017/02/bees-can-train-each-other-to-use-tools/)

Once you have converted your data to z scores the data will have a mean value of zero and a standard deviation of 1, which should make it easier to analyze and map.  For example, since your data will be expressed in standard deviations any value between -1 and 1 is (roughly) average.